# Manipulate expression produces error messages

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, warning-messages

I need to create the following: given two points on the surface of a unit sphere and a third one (that can be varied through `Manipulate`), find the point on the sphere that minimises the sum of the arc distances and then visualise the result. My attempt is based on the following code:

```
Arc3D[{a_, b_, m_}, n_: 60, prim_: Line] := 
  Module[{α, lab, axis, aarc, tm, alpha}, 
   lab = m + Norm[a - m]*Normalize[b - m];
   axis = (a - m)\[Cross](b - m);
   aarc = (VectorAngle[a - m, b - m]);
   tm = RotationMatrix[alpha, axis];
   prim @ Table[m + tm.(a - m), {alpha, 0, aarc, aarc/n}]];

or = {0, 0, 0};
u1 = 0;
f1 = 0;
u2 = Pi/3;
f2 = 0;
q = {Sin[u1] Cos[f1], Sin[u1] Sin[f1], Cos[u1]};
w = {Sin[u2] Cos[f2], Sin[u2] Sin[f2], Cos[u2]};
e := {Sin[u3] Cos[f3], Sin[u3] Sin[f3], Cos[u3]};
min := 
  NMinimize[
    {ArcCos[Cos[u1] Cos[ux] + Sin[u1] Sin[ux] Cos[f1 - fx]] + 
     ArcCos[Cos[u2] Cos[ux] + Sin[u2] Sin[ux] Cos[f2 - fx]] + 
     ArcCos[Cos[u3] Cos[ux] + Sin[u3] Sin[ux] Cos[f3 - fx]], 
     ux >= 0, ux <= Pi, fx >= 0, fx < 2 Pi}, {ux, fx}];
Ux := min[[2, 1, 2]];
Fx := min[[2, 2, 2]];
S := {Sin[Ux] Cos[Fx], Sin[Ux] Sin[Fx], Cos[Ux]};
```

followed by

```
Manipulate[
  Show[
    Graphics3D[
      {{Opacity[0.3], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}, 
       {Blue, Arc3D[{q, w, or}, 20]}, 
       {Blue, Arc3D[{w, e, or}, 20]}, 
       {Blue, Arc3D[{e, q, or}, 20]}, 
       {Green, Arc3D[{e, S, or}, 20]}, 
       {Green, Arc3D[{q, S, or}, 20]}, 
       {Green, Arc3D[{w, S, or}, 20]}, 
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, q}],
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, w}], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, e}], 
       {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, S}]}}], 
    Boxed -> False], 
  {{u3, Pi/2}, 0, Pi}, 
  {{f3, Pi/2}, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

which however returns a ton of errors. The code works if I remove the `Manipulate` command and I specify the coordinates for the third points, i.e. $e$, by giving explicit values to the angles $ux$ and $fx$. Thus, although the code is in principle working, it is the ``dynamic" part (user can change the $e$ point through manipulate) that fails.

Regarding the code, command `Arc3D` draws arcs between two points given their coordinates (ignore this part of the code as it is definitely working), `min` is the result of the numerical minimisation of the sum of the arc distances that are assigned to `Ux` and `Fx` and `S` are the cartesian coordinates of this ``minimal arc sum'' point.

All points are uniquely specified by the two angles $u,f$ but cartesian coordinates are also needed for drawing the arcs.

Can anyone find the error in my code and help me correct it?

An example of a working code ($e$ point specified in advance and no `Manipulate` command) returns the following graphic:
[image]

which is exactly what I want to do but with the addition of being able to dynamically change one of the points.

Comment: The control variables `u3` and `f3` in your `Manipulate` expression are local to that expression and are, therefore, not the same as the global free variables `u3` and `f3` appearing outside the `Manipulate` expression. That is the first thing you should fix.

Comment: OK, thnx. I will try to correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general comment I'd say that it is always best to avoid having so many global variables around, and even more avoid having implicit dependence on some other variable, like you have for your functions `q`, `w`, `e` ecc.

In fact, I modified your code localizing all the variables, and doing nothing more than that, and it turned out to work perfectly:

```
Arc3D[{a_, b_, m_}, n_: 60, prim_: Line] := 
  Module[{lab, axis, aarc, tm, alpha},
   lab = m + Norm[a - m]*Normalize[b - m];
   axis = (a - m)\[Cross](b - m);
   aarc = (VectorAngle[a - m, b - m]);
   tm = RotationMatrix[alpha, axis];
   prim@Table[m + tm.(a - m), {alpha, 0, aarc, aarc/n}]
   ];

q[u1_, f1_] := {Sin[u1] Cos[f1], Sin[u1] Sin[f1], Cos[u1]};
w[u2_, f2_] := {Sin[u2] Cos[f2], Sin[u2] Sin[f2], Cos[u2]};
e[u3_, f3_] := {Sin[u3] Cos[f3], Sin[u3] Sin[f3], Cos[u3]};
min[u1_, f1_, u2_, f2_, u3_, f3_] := NMinimize[
   {
    ArcCos[Cos[u1] Cos[ux] + Sin[u1] Sin[ux] Cos[f1 - fx]] +
     ArcCos[Cos[u2] Cos[ux] + Sin[u2] Sin[ux] Cos[f2 - fx]] +
     ArcCos[Cos[u3] Cos[ux] + Sin[u3] Sin[ux] Cos[f3 - fx]],
    ux >= 0, ux <= Pi, fx >= 0, fx < 2 Pi
    },
   {ux, fx}
   ];
Ux[u1_, f1_, u2_, f2_, u3_, f3_] := 
  min[u1, f1, u2, f2, u3, f3][[2, 1, 2]];
Fx[u1_, f1_, u2_, f2_, u3_, f3_] := 
  min[u1, f1, u2, f2, u3, f3][[2, 2, 2]];
S[u1_, f1_, u2_, f2_, u3_, f3_] := With[{
    ux = Ux[u1, f1, u2, f2, u3, f3],
    fx = Fx[u1, f1, u2, f2, u3, f3]
    },
   {Sin[ux] Cos[fx], Sin[ux] Sin[fx], Cos[ux]}
   ];

With[
 {u1 = 0, u2 = Pi/3, f1 = 0, f2 = 0, or = {0, 0, 0}},
 Manipulate[
  With[
   {q = q[u1, f1], w = w[u2, f2]},
   Module[{localS},
    localS[u3_, f3_] := S[u1, f1, u2, f2, u3, f3];
    Show[
     Graphics3D[{
       {Opacity[0.3], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]},
       {Blue, Arc3D[{q, w, or}, 20]},
       {Blue, Arc3D[{w, e[u3, f3], or}, 20]},
       {Blue, Arc3D[{e[u3, f3], q, or}, 20]},
       {Green, Arc3D[{e[u3, f3], localS[u3, f3], or}, 20]},
       {Green, Arc3D[{q, localS[u3, f3], or}, 20]},
       {Green, Arc3D[{w, localS[u3, f3], or}, 20]},
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, q}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, w}], 
       Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, e[u3, f3]}],

       {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, localS[u3, f3]}]}
       }
      ],
     Boxed -> False
     ]
    ]
   ],
  {{u3, Pi/2}, 0, Pi}, {{f3, Pi/2}, 0, 2 Pi}
  ]
 ]
```

which produces the expected (I hope?) result:
[image]

Comment: This still gives me a ft of errors.

Comment: Same for me. I first run the definitions in one cell and then the `With[...]' command but I get an error and the definitions are lost, as if the kernel quit and restarted.

Comment: I have 10.4.1.0 running on a Mac. I restarted Mathematica and run your code again but still did not work.

Comment: nevermind, I figured why. I didn't notice that `min` also used the values of `u1`, `f1`, `u2`, `f2`. I'll fix that and it will probably start working again

Comment: It is indeed working if the definitions of `min`, `Ux`, `Fx` and `S` are modified accordingly.

Comment: @AG1123 yup, see the updated code. It is admittedly a little longer due to the use of the `With` and `Module` to properly localise all the variables, and the specification of all the input variables to the functions, but it is a safer way to write code (and it is also much easier to find bugs)

Comment: It is now working as intended. Some errors for certain values of the angles are due to the math not carefully worked out and not due to the code. Thanks for the help!